# Mail merge Microsoft outlook informs into Microsoft forms

Tags: outlook, mailmerge, microsoft-forms

How do I create a mail merge in Microsoft that will merge information from a outlook template email into a Microsoft form?

I cannot seem to find any directions on how to do so. This is my first attempt at a mail merge. I’ve reviewed documentation on how to merge Microsoft form responses into a outlook email but nothing to transfer data from the email template into the Microsoft form.